# python lambda VS. def func():

Tags: python, pandas

the following two functions should be the same but when I used lambda, I keep getting

> "ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0')"

What is the reason lambda did not work?

------this gives ValueError-------------

```
df['flag']= df.apply(lambda x: 1 if df.a> df.b or df.a < df.c else 0, axis=1)
```

--------however this works------------

```
def flagout(df):
    if df.a> df.b:
        return 1
    elif df.a< df.c:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['flag'] = df.apply(flagout, axis=1)
```

Comment: does `df['flag']= df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (df.a> df.b) | (df.a < df.c) else 0, axis=1)` work?

Comment: Your `lambda` ignores its parameter, but the function doesn't.

Comment: `def flagout(df):` takes a parameter `df` – `lambda x:` takes `x` as the parameter name (but still uses `df` in its body which refers to something else).

Comment: Your lambda and your function are a bit weird as you're iterating row-wise and passing the row in the method version but in your lambda you are iterating row-wise but trying to compare the entire df

Comment: got it. the mistake was in the lambda I used df. instead of the real parameter x. Now it's working well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is stating that you're comparing an array with a scalar which is semantically different to comparing just scalar values:

```
In [55]:    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[55]:
          a         b         c
0  0.273142 -0.961078  0.715027
1  0.131964  1.049724 -0.928581
2 -1.015484 -1.927166 -1.633281
3  0.766749 -0.312187 -0.473424
4 -0.427227  1.105844 -0.125702
```

if you change the lambda to use the actual row value then it works as desired:

```
In [56]:
df['flag']= df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x.a> x.b) | (x.a < x.c) else 0, axis=1)
df

Out[56]:
          a         b         c  flag
0  0.273142 -0.961078  0.715027     1
1  0.131964  1.049724 -0.928581     0
2 -1.015484 -1.927166 -1.633281     1
3  0.766749 -0.312187 -0.473424     1
4 -0.427227  1.105844 -0.125702     1
```

here:

```
df['flag']= df.apply(lambda x: 1 if df.a> df.b or df.a < df.c else 0, axis=1)
```

you defined a lambda variable `x` but then completely ignore it by doing `df.a > df.b` and so besides even if this did work it's wrong because you're comparing arrays rather than scalar values

Besides it's faster and more scalable to use `np.where` in this situation:

```
In [57]:
df['flag']= np.where((df.a> df.b) | (df.a < df.c),1,0)
df

Out[57]:
          a         b         c  flag
0  0.273142 -0.961078  0.715027     1
1  0.131964  1.049724 -0.928581     0
2 -1.015484 -1.927166 -1.633281     1
3  0.766749 -0.312187 -0.473424     1
4 -0.427227  1.105844 -0.125702     1
```

This uses the boolean mask on the entire df and then sets the row values in a vectorised manner

**timings**

```
In [61]:
%%timeit
def flagout(df):
    if df.a> df.b:
        return 1
    elif df.a< df.c:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
​
df.apply(flagout, axis=1)

1 loops, best of 3: 284 ms per loop

In [59]:

%timeit np.where((df.a> df.b) | (df.a < df.c),1,0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 560 µs per loop
```

You can see that on a 4k row df, `np.where` is ~600x faster

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your lambda is equivalent to your function flagout.

Your lambda should be `lambda x: 1 if x.a> x.b or x.a < x.c else 0` in order to be equivalent to your function.